# How can I send a 16 bit word useing Python socket.send() instead of a 8bit one

Tags: python, sockets, binary, hex, spi

I trying to build up an SPI communication between my PC and a sensor-device. For that, I use a TCP/IP to SPI Converter. This side of the project is already working. I can send something over TCP/IP to the converter and it does its job.

So where is the problem? I use the socket lib. in Python 3.8 to do the TCP/IP side:

```
import socket, sys

TCP_IP = '192.168.100.100'
TCP_PORT = 1003
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket()

try:
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

except socket.error as mag:
    print (" Socket Erroer: " + str(mag))

s.send(b'\x8000')
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print(data)
```

What I want to do is to send (in **binary**) **1000 0000 0000 0000**  (= 8000 in Hex).
But python split the \x8000 into \x80\x00 and send it as two 8 bit words as 1000 0000 and then a second package 0000 0000. But the converter needs it as a 16 bit word otherwise, it fills it up. And the SPI-signal is **0000 0000** 1000 0000 **0000 0000** 0000 0000, that's terrible, I can't read a single register without the first 8 bits.

So is there a way to send /x8000 as one 16 bit word?
I would also like to know more about the datatype (or whatever it is) **b'** something **'** what is that? What does it?

Thank you for reading this! I'm open to all suggestions and critics. I hope you can help me thank you for every attempt!

Comment: No, you can't send a 16 bit word over a socket, but you can send two 8 bit words.

Comment: Okay... that's uncool, between two 8 bit is too long time for the converter

Comment: Is that a genaral thing of TCP/IP? Or can I solve it with a  diffent lib or language?

Comment: Its a TCP thing that, although a stream, each unit is an octet, usually called a byte. Now, you can form another protocol over TCP and turn the stream back into packets. There must be hundreds of options. Start by looking for [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)

Comment: Have you considered to use `libiio` https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python [raw socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.SOCK_RAW) to include 16bits in a single packet and send.

`b'something'` is python notation that converts the string "something" into its binary form(bytes), by default with `utf-8`.
For example if you code `a=b'Hello'`, `a` will have `\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that tip. But I don't understand how to use the raw socket. If I do s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP) like in the exampel on the page below. I get an error.

in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [WinError 10013] Der Zugriff auf einen Socket war aufgrund der Zugriffsrechte des Sockets unzulässig

Comment: Please refer [this](https://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/) link. It may be useful for you.